# cakephp query with subquery style

Tags: mysql, cakephp

how do I convert this query to CakePHP find style?

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM worksheet_forms ORDER BY id DESC) WorksheetForm
where company_id = '000002'
GROUP BY WorksheetForm.generated_id
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can see this example may be its help you

http://blog.burlock.org/open-source/136-cakephp-and-subqueries